# What is tonal masking?

Tags: electrical-engineering, telecommunication, acoustics, sound-isolation, electronic-filters

I have checked the definition of tonal masking on Wikipedia and google but I saw the definition of sound masking and auditory masking.

- [Auditory masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_masking)
- [Sound masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_masking)

But I want to know what exactly is tonal masking?

Comment: Providing more context about where you came across the term(s) would help the community provide you with a more focused answer.

Comment: What do you understand by the word "tonal"?

Comment: Would you ask somebody to provide more context about where they came across the terms inductance and capacitance if they asked a question about electrical circuits? This is all perfectly standard terminology in psychoacoustics, and noise masking is certainly "engineering" IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tonal masking is using tones at specific frequencies for sound masking, as compared with using noise containing a continuous band of frequencies.

In most practical situations noise is more effective for masking than tones, but experiments with pure tones are a way to try to understand how masking actually "works" in human hearing.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is looking for noise cancellation equipment or techniques and has had issues from translations...